# System.IO.FileInfo Case Insensitive Search

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is some code that I modified and originally copied from here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546159.aspx

I am searching a directory for file names and it works fine except I cannot figure out how to make it case **insensitive**

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(startFolder);

 // This method assumes that the application has discovery permissions 
 // for all folders under the specified path.
 IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileList = dir.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

 //Create the query
 IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileQuery =
     from file in fileList
     where file.Extension == ".pdf"
     where file.Name.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
     orderby file.Name
     select file;
```

This line contains the error:

```
where file.Name.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

The error is:

```
Error   1   'string' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, TSource, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments  C:\Users\k5opjdjc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test_File_Search\Test_File_Search\Controllers\SearchController.cs   30  23  Test_File_Search
```

I have searched for  a few hours now and can not locate an answer. If someone could help, I would be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
where file.Name.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
```

(`IndexOf` returns -1 when no matching substring is found)